# Calculate the rank of a circular matrix over GF(2)

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

How can we calculate the rank of a large circular matrix over GF(2) efficiently ? for instance ( 10^6* 10^6 matrix ) ( Best algorithm )

Comment: $10^6$ is a relatively small number. The ordinary Gauss-Jordan method should work.

Comment: Any usefull link to the ordinary Gauss-Jordn method

Comment: Here you can find a faster method using Fourier transform (see the Applications section). It also has a link to  Gaussian reduction.

Comment: could you give me the link of the two methods ? ( where 's the application section ? )

Comment: Sorry! Here it is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix

Comment: By solving C*X=b with C the circulant matrix how can i find the rank ?

Comment: Actually finding the rank is easier: look at the section Rank of the same text.